# Switching Primary and Secondary Y Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a dataset that includes the number of High/Medium/Low issues in a project, as well as the percentage of how complete it is. I'm trying to get the % complete to be the primary y axis, and the secondary to be the number of issues. I am using a stacked bar graph for the High/Medium/Low issues.

What I'm trying to achieve is the bar graphs rising to the correct percentages according to the primary y axis, and then having a label to distinguish the number of issues in each bar graph segment (ultimately hiding the secondary y axis).

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQvj.png) Ignore the line graph representing the %, I'd ultimately want to not have a line at all, and just use the stacked bar graphs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(note: I assumed you table was in `A1:E7`)

1. Add new columns with the following formula in `F2`, populate over and down and format the cells as %:

   =(B2/SUM($B2:$D2)*$E2)

[image]

2. Insert a stacked column chart:
3. Right-click on the chart and choose "Select Data" from the drop-down menu
4. Make sure your row labels are on the right-hand side (click on "Switch Row/Column" if need be)

[image]

5. remove the first four columns from the chart

[image]

6. Click "OK". your chart should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: In this use case, there is at least a value of 1 or more in each High/Medium/Low tab. In the case that there is all 0's, the complete percentage does not show. Do you know how this can be resolved?