# Displaying number and percent in stacked bar graph with double Y Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have multiple ongoing projects, with data in Excel. 
Each project has zero or more issues associated with it,
as well as a percentage representing how complete the project is. 
Each issue is of high, medium, or low importance (and I have the number of each).

I want to display the status of each project as a stacked bar graph
with three sections that display how many high/medium/low issues there are,
and the bar grows horizontally to show the percentage complete. 
For example:

[image: chart]

The project has 3 high, 1 medium, and 2 low issues and is 30% complete. 
Here is the data the graph pulls:

```
        |    B     |    C     |    D     |     E      |    F     |    G     |    H     |
        | High     | Medium   | Low      | % Complete | High     | Medium   | Low      |
(row 25)|       3  |       1  |       2  |        30% |      15% |       5% |      10% |
```

In order to calculate the percentages in F25, G25, H25 I need to manipulate the data so that it equals the percentage. For example, to calculate the percentage in F25, I do `=(B25/SUM($B25:$D25)*$E25)`.

My issue is in the case where a graph is more than 0% complete (at least 10%) and has 0 total issues. This will not populate a bar on the graph whatsoever.

My issue is very similar to this question: [Switching Primary and Secondary Y Axis](https://superuser.com/questions/1439928/switching-primary-and-secondary-y-axis)

How can I display the percent complete for a project that has no issues,
while following the above scheme for projects that have issue(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix Columns `F`, `G` and `H`
so they don’t get errors for a project with no issues. 
The easy way is to change the formula in `F25` to

```
=IFERROR(B25/SUM($B25:$D25)*$E25, 0)
```

Second, add Column `I` to pick up the slack
and ensure that you have a bar when you have no issues:

```
=IF(SUM($B25:$D25)=0, E25, 0)
```

[image: chart and data]